# Buzzfeed styled quiz with generated answer based on chosen checkboxes in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a quiz type system where the user is given two questions that they are asked two questions. For example a quiz where the user is asked what stop they like to determine what stop they could play, kind of like something that is on buzzfeed.

I would like to create something similar to http://www.playbuzz.com/oliviagrace10/what-female-singer-are-you

The questions will be added using a html form and the users will be displayed with check boxes for the user to click for there answer, as shown below.

```html
<form>

<p>What Sport Have You Played Before?</p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="football">Football<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="rugby"> Rugby<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="basketball"> Basketball
</form>
```

Once the user clicks submit I want the system to give an answer based on  what the user has clicked, for example if they pick football and rugby then it will display that they could play basketball.

I had tried to do this manual before by having the check buttons with different names and have the information stored in a database and say that if button 1 and 2 are clicked then show an answer as shown below. This was taking to long and quite hard to do.

```html
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

if (isset($_POST['sport1'], $_POST['sport2'])) {

      $query = "SELECT * FROM sports WHERE ID = 5";

      $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid Query");

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 

      echo "<p>";

      echo $row[1];

      echo "</p>";
  
  }
}
```

What is the best way to create something like this using php? Would it be easier to do this was javascript?

Comment: I think php is better because if you build it with javascript I do not know how to prevent users from cheating via looking at the source code..

Comment: If you do it in php and a database, you will have to connect back to the database every time a user submits something. If it is done in Javascript all the information is stored in the user's browser - and as @frankenapps mentioned, cheating is possible via the source code. Depends if you care about that or not. It is possible to connect to a database using javascript, but it is not recommended.

Comment: yeah think I will stick to using php, what is the best way to do this in php?

Comment: what I want to create something like this http://www.playbuzz.com/oliviagrace10/what-female-singer-are-you only allowing the users to chose multiple answers.